# Writing to file in Documents folder in internal storage

Tags: java, android, document, fileoutputstream, internal-storage

I've been trying to save text to a file in the documents folder in internal storage to be accessed by file manager so i can read it, I've tried several methods including using a writer, but I can't seem to get it to work, I'm not trying to save to external storage, I don't have external storage, only internal, and that's where my documents folder is, so I'm assuming I don't have to bother with the permissions in manifest, I threw in the setReadable just in case but I still can't find it in the documents folder, this is where I'm currently  at.

```
public void writeToFile(String string){
        
try {
            
            File file = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS, "myFile.txt");
            file.setReadable(true);
            FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            stream.write(string.getBytes(string));
            stream.flush();
            stream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: `a file in the documents folder in internal storage` I'm not aware of such a folder.

Comment: `I'm not trying to save to external storage ` Wel you should as in root of external storage there is a Documents folder.

Comment: I don't have external storage, only internal, and that's where my documents folder is

Comment: First of let me say thank you, I tried it and it worked, but I'm confused because in file explorer I click on internal storage, with no external strorage option, then Documents, and when I tried your method it worked and that's where it was, but why does file explorer consider it internal while java considers it external

Comment: That is all for historic reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > File file = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS, "myFile.txt");

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "myFile.txt");
```

Comment: I don't have external storage only internal storage

Comment: Every device has internal and external storage.